# Jar is not getting executed in Maven based project in netbeans

Tags: java, maven

Hi I'm working on project which created in netbeans 8.0.1.
It is created in Maven.Now after completion when try to open created jar its not getting executed.
below is the pom.xml file.

Please advise.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.elitechweb.asm</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
 <build>

 </build>

</project>
```

Comment: use `mvn clean` and `mvn install` command from your working directory

Comment: It's show Java Home Variable not set in Environment Variable.But I'm using netbeans it automatically create jar.But main class is not getting executed

Comment: What you do you mean `"when try to open created jar"`? Do you mean `run` (java -jar yourjar.jar), rather than `open`?

Comment: _Do you_ have the `JAVA_HOME` env-var set?

Comment: yup Java Env-var is there but not for Maven.I directly started working in netbeans.

Comment: guys done.Simply need to add maven-install-plugin-2.3.1 jar and give location.

Answer (score 0):

Added maven-install-plugin-2.3.1 jar file. and changes in POM.xml respective jar